# Business Intelligence Application for iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, business-intelligence

I have some experience in iPhone development. Now one client wants to develop a BI (Business Intelligence) related iPad app for their organisation.

As I have no previous experience in development of such an application, I googled a bit & learned that these BI related apps show various data present in an organisation in various chart/graphical formats to the user.

Q1) So what is the best way to pull these data from server?

Q2) Also is there any API / Framework available to do this kind of app in iPad?

If anyone has any other suggestions, please post here.

Answer (score 2):

1. There are a TON of ways to do this.  You can build it with most any technology that your organization uses.  The main key is to keep a clear separation of tiers.  Build a web application that queries your database and have it present the information as XML or JSON.  You can then parse the data and present it in your iOS application.
2. For actually doing data visualization, you will want to take a look at Core-Plot.  I've used it on projects and it has worked well: http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/

Answer (score 0):

If your customer wants an out-of-the-box solution for getting their BI on mobile devices, take a look at Actuate/BIRT.  They have a simple way to get it into mobile.